# Make Launchpad icons smaller again

Tags: launchpad, macos

The 10.7.2 upgrade made the launchpad icons bigger which I'm finding incredibly annoying as before I could see all my icons at once, but now because of there being less space between icons my eyes just focus on one icon at a time.

[image]

How can I make the icons smaller again? Is there some hidden setting or string I can change (e.g. using terminal)?

Comment: They got bigger? I haven't noticed any change. Just curious: what's your screen resolution? How many icons you had in a view before update and have now?

Comment: Same number of icons (just less space between them), same resolution(1440*900), and other people have had this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [OS X Daily](http://www.osxdaily.com/2011/10/19/change-launchpad-icon-size-large-to-small/), if you replace the 10.7.2 Dock binary with the 10.7.1 dock binary, the icons will resume their diminutive size.

Answer (score 2):

I tried replacing the "dock" folder in System > core services with that one from 10.7.1, it actually made launchpad icons smaller again, but at every start up it takes some time to load the dock an the desktop background, and the dock is not working properly, I'm trying to figure it out changing something in the dock folder instead of replacing it whole.