# Are the LaunchPad icons bigger/magnified in Mac OS 10.7.2?

Tags: macos, launchpad

Just upgraded to 10.7.2 and found out that the Launchpad icons had become much bigger / magnified.

Is this a normal thing or is there something wrong with my installation?

Comment: For reverting the size, see: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27514/make-launchpad-icons-smaller-again

Comment: @koiyu *"but at every start up it takes some time to load the dock [and] the desktop background, and the dock is not working properly"* Far from a viable solution.

Comment: @cksum Yes, by a mile. What I meant was it is better to collect all the answers to one question rather than scattering them around to duplicate (sub)questions on the site. Perhaps you could provide an answer that reverting the size is impossible?

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes, they are bigger.
2. No, the size is hardcoded in the actual application.

Comment: How do you know it's hardcoded? There could be a hidden preference or something inside Dock's bundle that could be tweaked.

Comment: No. It's hardcoded. Feel free to root around if you like.